# Can a single cell in Excel extend over several pages? How?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I encountered this problem while trying to write really large chunks of text in Excel. In spite of of wrapping turned on, my text doesn't really get wrapped once it stretches over more than 12 lines (the cell B3 in the screenshot). I am actually able to continue writing but the cell size doesn't accomodate to the extent of the written text. The only way to read the whole content of the cell is in the box that appears to the top of the selected cell. That text, however, does not keep the formatting of the original text and is therefore difficult to read. Is it possible to make a table in Excel with really huge cells - extending maybe over 2/3 pages? Cell merging doesn't seem to help much. It would require dividing the text into several cells and that isn't very practical, I think. Thanks in advance.

[image: Too much text for the cell]

Comment: This smells of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Excel is a spreadsheet not a word processor.

Comment: Consider using a **REALLY BIG** TextBox.

Comment: Or convert it to an image and spread that across as a shape? I've with @David on this one.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it possible to make a table in Excel with huge cells - extending over 2/3 pages?

Probably not (unless you upgrade your version of Excel).

Excel 2003 can only **display** 1024 characters in each cell (even though a cell can contain up to 32,767 characters).

Later versions of Excel removed the limitation, and will display cells containing up to 32,767 characters.

> In Excel there are two separate limitations at play: a limit on what
>   can be entered in a cell and a limit on what can be displayed. In most
>   cases, the limit on what can be entered in a cell is not a real issue;
>   Excel allows you to enter up to 32,767 characters in each cell. All of
>   these characters will show up in the Formula bar just fine.
>
> The problem comes with the display limitation. There is a limit that
>   Excel will display only the first 1,024 characters in each cell. In
>   other words, if there is anything more than this in a cell (which
>   could be likely in some circumstances), then it won't display; Excel
>   pretends like it isn't even there. You can't get around this limit by
>   changing fonts, cell sizes, wrapping status, or anything else.

...

> In later versions of Excel (after Excel 2003) Microsoft changed the display limits to match those of the cell entry limits. In other words, you can enter and display up to 32,767 characters in later versions of Excel.

Source [Character Limits for Cells](http://excel.tips.net/T003163_Character_Limits_for_Cells.html)

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use Merged cells to accomplish this. You must place the text in the topmost cell. Anything placed in lower cells before being merged will be wiped out.

The maximum height you can have for a cell is 409.5. So you can make some big rows if you wish, but it seems like you might just want to leave the row heights alone and just merge more cells rather than less.

Merging cells has "issues" in that many other regular bits of work done in places affected by them now cannot be done. But if you must have the full text visible, that is a way to do it.

Be sure to have "Wrap Text" selected for the cell formatting. or you may have some unhappiness that takes some formatting work.

Since you say that did not work for you, I must believe you had the text split between cells and then merged them. Just don't do that. Put all the text in the top cell, THEN do the merging until it fully displays.

Another way is to enter the data all in the top cell, then choose HOME on the Ribbon menu, highlight the cells you would like to fill, and over to the far right, in the EDITING group, choose FILL, then JUSTIFY. Excel will break up your data to fit the cells, as best it can if you didn't select enough cells. And it will lose what doesn't fit... So either be prepared to experiment with how many rows, using UNDO in between tries, or pick "surely too many" and see where it ends, then UNDO and select only the cells it used, then do it.

As for figuring out how many rows are on the page and therefore how many you have to use, tell Excel to Print, then escape out of that. You'll see dotted lines that tell you where the page limits would be. Now you can make sure you choose only cells on a single page. (So, if you would need more cells, widen the column instead until it fits in the available, single page's, cells.)